# Issue while installing Angular CLI on windows 11 with node version 18.12.1

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

I was trying to install angular cli and i had these two warning i'm afraid that will bother me later i don't know how to fix it help me please.....

```
C:\Users\ASUS>npm install -g @angular/cli
npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@2.0.1: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
npm WARN deprecated sourcemap-codec@1.4.8: Please use @jridgewell/sourcemap-codec instead

changed 231 packages, and audited 232 packages in 5s

26 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

After I tried to see the version of angular if it is installed. The cmd displayed this error.

```
C:\Users\ASUS>ng --version
Error: You need to specify a command before moving on. Use '--help' to view the available commands.
```

Answer (score 4):

Try the command `ng v` and check if it ask any question about google and say N as no. If it shows angular versions then it means `angular/cli` is installed

Answer (score 0):

i have install it with Yarn 
1.install Yarn
https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/#windows-stable
in my case i choosed msi download because it failled with npm

2. With Yarn installed Angular / cli
   yarn add @angular/cli
3. in environment variable I add the path this ng root
   INSTALLATION_PATH\node_modules.bin
   and now i have it globall.